# What does this syntax mean? Func<Task, TResult> sampleFunction

Tags: c#, types, casting, func

I have been using [`Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783447%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for while and just decided to examine other options. So I referred to it's **MSDN** reference page and the syntax for this commands is described as:

```
public Task<TResult> ContinueWhenAny<TResult>(
    Task[] tasks,
    Func<Task, TResult> continuationFunction,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
)
```

It's clear to me that the parts mentioned inside `<` & `>` are **types**, such as the expected return value of a type `TResult` in `Task<TResult>`. However I am not quite sure what this part of this syntax would mean:

```
Func<Task, TResult> continuationFunction
```

As you can see there are two parameters sandwiched inside `<>` and separated by a comma.

Comment: continuationFunction is 'A function that gets a Task and returns an object of type TResult'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a `Func` delegate and it's declared like this:

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

It represents a function that takes a `Task` parameter and returns a result of type `TResult`.

It is similar to:

```
TResult ContinuationFunction<T,TResult>(T arg) { ... }
```

Further reading

- [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)
- [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)
- [`Func<T, TResult>` Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The answer was right under my nose. Thanks for the replay anyways. This functions has lots of omitted parts I guess and it's very abbreviated. Will read along to understand the syntax even more.

Comment: @Mehrad, you need to read and master those articles. We are on the virge of C# 6.0 and generics were introduced in C$ 2.0. I wounder how you can get anything done with `Task`s and not know what generics are.

Comment: @PauloMorgado, I would say there is a difference between not knowing what something is and not knowing it's name. I bet you don't know what we call a "car" in Persian but you will well and truly be able to drive it no matter what people call it. :)
I'm not defending myself either. As the question states I am not ashamed of asking the question I don't know the answer for no matter how simple it looks and I know I gotta read to fill up the gap for when I dropped C when it became .Net and picking it up now with all these fancy stuff added to it. I respect you guys helping us.

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding (you did ask what that means and not how it's called). You should ask when you don't know (I do!). But you should also listen to the answers. Generics are old news and now required basic knowledge to program in C#. If your as near as crazy as I am, you will read [the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228593.aspx). :)